# Google Cloud Platform: Trigger Cloud Build via Cloud Storage event

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build

Does anyone successfully set up GCP Cloud Build trigger via pub/sub notification with Cloud Storage OBJECT_FINALIZE event (new object uploaded)?

I have followed the GCP documentation, but nothing worked. This is what I did:

1. Create a topic
2. Create a notification via gsutil as per documentation which sends a message to the topic upon OBJECT_FINALIZE event on Google Cloud Storage (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes)
3. Create the Cloud Build trigger with Pub/Sub subscription to the topic above
4. I also ensure that Cloud Build API is enabled and the cloud build service account has permissions to read the message from the topic

But when i uploaded new file to the Cloud Storage bucket, the build pipeline was never triggered.

Please help if you already set this up before. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried running using Docker file, and it triggers successfully when I upload a new file. Please verify if what configuration type you used in your project? Is it Cloud Build configuration file (yaml or json) or Dockerfile? Also, try to run your trigger/s manually and see if it would be successful.

Comment: It is Cloud Build yaml config, running the job manually work

Comment: Can you also check the permissions?

Comment: @guilaume blaquiere  what permissions specifically? I have checked permissions for the cloud build service account

Comment: It might be better to contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub#section-2) if you have an existing support package or free trial credits so they can properly check your setup.

Comment: Well I do not have Google Support package, that's why I asked here. The GCP documentation is not very good. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I followed your 2nd step (no added flags on `gsutil`), then this [link](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-pubsub-triggers#gcs_build_trigger), skipping the optionals. I used yaml config file as type and a GitHub repo as source. It is working without any problems. For us to help, could you please update your question and add more context and detail, so we can reproduce it? To get started, are all your resources within a single project? Are you the project and the bucket's owner? Did you specified a service account for the trigger? Feel free to add more info.